# Desktop icons are gone in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, desktop

My desktop icons are not showing up, and right click won't work, but the taskbar and all are there.
This happened after I set up a active desktop. Now I have removed it and changed the theme as well, but still no icons and right click on desktop still does not work.  How can I reset this?

Comment: You sound infected...what anti-malware programs have you run? Can you boot into safe mode and get your icons?

Comment: @KCotreau may be on the right track, lately malware has been hiding everyhing on the hard drive, which includes icons on the desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try #195 on here:

http://www.kellys-korner-xp.com/xp_tweaks.htm

if that doesnt work try <s>#256</s> #246 then in Task Manager kill the process called explorer.exe
then go <kbd>File</kbd>><kbd>New Task(Run...)</kbd> and type in `explorer.exe` and see if it works.

also try this:

http://www.winxptutor.com/showdesktopicons.htm

Comment: second link worked , explorer was running but dekstop icons only gone